# Yasnippet not working with auto-complete-mode

Tags: yasnippet, auto-complete-mode

I am just starting to experiment with Yasnippet, and it worked very well until I tried to combine it with `auto-complete-mode`. The problem is that Auto-Complete is taking over completely. For example, in `c-mode` I can type `pr` and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to expand a `printf` snippet, but after activating `auto-complete-mode` this does not work, but `auto-complete-mode` itself works just fine. Instead, I would like to have Yasnippet to have priority over Auto-Complete when I press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.

I am using Emacs 24.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, Yasnippet version: 0.8.1, and Auto-Complete version 1.5.0.

Here is minimal example

```
$ emacs -Q -l init.el t.c
```

where `init.el` is:

```el
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(yas-global-mode 1)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
(add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-yasnippet)
```

If I now type `pr` and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, I get the Auto-Complete popup menu, (whereas I would like to expand the `printf` snippet instead). If I type `M-x auto-complete-mode` to turn off `auto-complete-mode` and then type `pr` and <kbd>TAB</kbd>, the `printf` snippet expands as expected.

Other information:

- `C-h v RET ac-source-yasnippet` gives:

```
((depends yasnippet)
 (candidates . ac-yasnippet-candidates)
 (action . yas/expand)
 (candidate-face . ac-yasnippet-candidate-face)
 (selection-face . ac-yasnippet-selection-face)
 (symbol . "a"))
```

- `C-h v RET ac-sources` gives:

```
(ac-source-yasnippet ac-source-gtags ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers)
```

- Clearing `ac-source-yasnippet` variable (`(setq ac-source-yasnippet nil)`) does not help.

---

**References:**

- [About auto complete and yasnippet in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869178/about-auto-complete-and-yasnippet-in-emacs)
- [emacs 24 autocomplete yasnippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774807/emacs-24-autocomplete-yasnippet)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a workaround, you can redefine the Yasnippet expansion key instead, as explained in the [FAQ](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/faq.html):

```el
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<C-tab>") 'yas-expand)
```

In this way, you use `<C-tab>` to expand Yasnippets and the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key for `auto-complete-mode`.

---

**Note:**

I also discovered that using `<C-tab>` to expand Yasnippets, instead of `<tab>`, had the advantage to make snippet expansion not interfer with `indent-according-to-mode`. For example: If I have a Lisp line: `(ac-config-default)` but it is not correctly indented, I usually press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to indent it correctly (using `indent-according-to-mode`). But if the cursor were between the `a` and `c` in `(ac-config-default)` it would instead have expanded the Lisp `and`-snippet (which is not desired here), to get the line `((and )c-config-default))`..